# problema con rxjs/operators

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, rxjs

tengo un servicio en node que llamo a traves de una aplicacion hecha en angular
cree un servicio para consumirla la api y también use map para transformar la respuesta , mi problema es que cuando llamo el servicio a un componente este me retorna undefined
este mi servicio donde consumo la api ya intente de todo

```
  buscar(tipo: 'usuarios' | 'productos' | 'categorias' | 'ventas' | 'movimientos', termino: string = '') {
    const url = `${base_url}/buscar/${tipo}/${termino}`
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url, this.headers).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp.results) //aca si resuelve la información correcta 
        resp.results 
      }
      )
    )
  }
```

este es el codigo de mi componente

```
 buscar(termino: string) {
    console.log(termino)
    this.busquedaServices.buscar('usuarios', termino).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp)// aca me retorna undefine no entiendo por que pueda pero en el servicio si retorna como debe de ser
      }
    )
  }
```

y esto es lo que resuelve por consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta "return" delante de `resp.results`, en la última línea de la función que le pasas a map

Answer (score -1):

Dentro del map tienes que retornar el resultado:

```
return resp.results
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta, puedes marcarla como correcta cuando compruebes que te funciona o comentar si no te funciona